# Getting an error after loading sound effect and a sound effect instance

Tags: xna

```
ExplosionSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("explosion");
            ExplosionSoundInstance = ExplosionSound.CreateInstance();
```

The last line of the above code is underlined and i get an error stating:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance' to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect'.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you were declared ExplosionSoundInstance as SoundEffect...

Declare it as SoundEffectInstance....

```
SoundEffectInstance ExplosionSoundInstance;
```